# How to help my dog remember a long term human friend after just 4 weeks apart?

Tags: dogs, behavior, introducing-pets

My friend and I moved to another country with our dog, Jack. My friend left earlier and, after 2 months, I brought our dog to a new place. Now our dog doesn't recognise my friend after 4 weeks even though my friend has been with him for almost 9 years. He only remembers me now and follows me all around. He used to chase my friend.

Nothing has changed with my friend's appearance such as beard / hair etc. He is recognisable as the same person.

Does anyone has any ideas to help our dog retrieve his memory? I read so many amazing stories from the forums that dogs have a long lasting memory about their owners. Hope our dog can get his memory back too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just treat the pup normally. Jack's been through a lot in the last couple of months. Your friend left, you moved, he probably went into quarantine for a little while, and instead of going back home, he's in a new home and the friend is back. He's probably a little confused and still getting used to his new environment. He is favoring you because you didn't leave, so you are his "rock". Act "normal" around Jack, as he becomes more comfortable in your new home/country, he'll open back up to your friend.